# How to select url from search results in Selenium C#?

Tags: c#, selenium

How can i select third result from google search using Selenium via Chrome?

```
 driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://google.com");
 driver.FindElement(By.Id("lst-ib")).SendKeys(word);
 driver.FindElement(By.Id("lst-ib")).SendKeys(Keys.Enter);
```

Now i want to select third result and open this url.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try:

```
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com");
driver.FindElement(By.Id("lst-ib")).SendKeys("Microsoft");
driver.FindElement(By.Id("lst-ib")).SendKeys(Keys.Enter);

IList<IWebElement> h3Links = driver.FindElements(By.TagName("h3"));

string myUrl = h3Links[2].FindElement(By.TagName("a")).GetAttribute("href");
```

That will insert all result links in one list collection as WebElemets objects after that you can use them

Comment: you have item in the list?

Comment: Yeah, links.count returns "59". But myUrl is still empty